# Custom Excel VBA formula generates #VALUE! only on automatic calculate

Tags: excel, vba

I have a cell "A" with a complicated formula involving 2 custom functions / formula.

I understand that when a cell changes value, Excel automatically recalculates all its dependant cells. When cell "A" gets updated from this mechanism, it gives #VALUE!.

Without doing anything else, I select cell "A" > hit F2 (edit) > then hit enter (exit edit), the value of cell "A" gets recalculated and gives correct value.

**EDIT 1**: Out of these [keyboard shortcuts](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/excel-help/change-formula-recalculation-iteration-or-precision-HP010054149.aspx#BMrecalculate_a_worksheet_or_workbook_m) only CTRL+ALT+SHIFT+F9 gives correct value. All others give #VALUE! if the function does not have `Application.Volatile`.

The formula:

```
=HLOOKUPRANGE(arr(CB43,CC43,CE43),Q!$CD$3:$DG$28,CG43)
```

VBA functions in question:

```
Public Function arr(ParamArray fields() As Variant)
    arr = fields
End Function

Public Function HLOOKUPRANGE(headers() As Variant, lookup_range As Range, row_index As Integer) As Variant
    If lookup_range.Columns.Count = 1 Then
        HLOOKUPRANGE = lookup_range(row_index, 1)
    Else
        ' look at the first row in the range for the header
        For colStart = 1 To lookup_range.Columns.Count Step 1
            col = lookup_range.Cells(1, colStart).Value
            If col = headers(1) Then
                colEnd = colStart + lookup_range.Cells(1, colStart).MergeArea.Columns.Count - 1
                Exit For
            End If
        Next

        ' set the new smaller range
        First = lookup_range.Cells(2, colStart).Address
        Last = lookup_range.Cells(lookup_range.Rows.Count, colEnd).Address
        Dim szRange As String
        szRange = First & ":" & Last

        ' set the new headers array
        Dim header_next() As Variant
        If UBound(headers) > 1 Then
            ReDim header_next(1 To UBound(headers) - 1)
            For i = LBound(headers) + 1 To UBound(headers) Step 1
                header_next(i - 1) = headers(i)
            Next
        End If

        HLOOKUPRANGE = HLOOKUPRANGE(header_next, Range(szRange), row_index)
    End If
End Function
```

The combined work of the functions is to navigate a lookup table from the headers in a top down fashion and return a value in the table based on the string headers defined in arr().

**EDIT 1**: When checking the Calculation Steps, arr() evalutes correctly into HLOOKRANGE({"hdr1","hdr2","hdr3"},Q!$CD$3:$DG$28,CG43), but this result evaluates into #VALUE!

Comment: What happens if you add this line of code `Application.Volatile` just before `If lookup_range.Columns.Count = 1 Then`?

Comment: @SiddharthRout you got it there, but not quite. Before, F2 > enter on the cell only updates that cell with correct value. After adding Application.Volatile, F2 > enter updates all cells with the HLOOKRANGE function and gives correct value. Automatic update still gives #VALUE!.

Comment: Try putting `Application.Volatile` in both the functions and see if it helps?

Comment: Just tried. No it does not work. Same behavior as my last comment. Please see my post again for updated edits. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the Range() function when invoked, has `Application.ActiveSheet` scope rather than the scope of the Worksheet that contains the cell formula of the same function.

Hence, to solve my problem, I need to explicitly call Range() from the correct worksheet e.g.

```
Dim rangeWorksheet as String
rangeWorksheet = lookup_range.Cells(2, colStart).Parent.Name
Dim curws As Worksheet
Set curws = Worksheets(rangeWorksheet)
curws.Range(...)
```

Comment: not until now. because I had to verify another question here first: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10344076/how-to-get-worksheet-and-cell-that-the-current-vba-function-is-returning-to   plus, it says i cannot mark it as answer until some days later.