# How to get worksheet and cell that the current VBA function is returning to?

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a variable anywhere that gives the worksheet and cell that will recieve the result of a custom VBA function?

For example, if in `A!B1` the formula is `=MyCustomFunc()` in my code:

```
public function MyCustomFunc()
    'what can I call here to get the values "A" and "B1"?
end function
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is this what you are trying?

```
Option Explicit

Public Function MyCustomFunc()
    '~~> Judicious use of 'Volatile' is advised.
    '~~> This will be called everytime the sheet is recalculated
    Application.Volatile

    MsgBox Application.Caller.Parent.Name & ", " & Application.Caller.Address
End Function
```

Comment: Yes, indeed. It's really hard to describe this in plain english. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You want `Application.ThisCell`.

This returns the cell which is currently being calculated.

Answer (score -1):

`ActiveSheet.Name` will give you sheet name. `ActiveCell.Row` will give you row number and `ActiveCell.Column` will give you column letter. Then you can combine them to get cell address.

Comment: Thanks, but Activecell gives, only the active cell. I do not want that. I want the cell and worksheet that will get the result of the function.